# issue listing items from parent MenuStripItem from MenuStrip in VB Net

Tags: vb.net

I have tried this code to list all SubItems from ToolStripMenuItem

```
For Each x As ToolStripMenuItem In FileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
    MsgBox(x.Text)
Next
```

but i get this error below

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator' to type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'.

Comment: Isnt the error clear?  The code `For Each x As ToolStripMenuItem` is trying to cast every item in the `DropDownItems` collection to a `ToolStripMenuItem` but the separator is not such an animal.  Also VS comes with a terrific set of debug tools less annoying and tedious than MsgBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ToolStripItem instead so you can filter out the ToolStripSeparator objects:

```
For Each x As ToolStripItem In FileToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
  If Not TypeOf x Is ToolStripSeparator Then
    MessageBox.Show(x.Text)
  End If
Next
```